# Usefulness of a Class Template for 2 types only

Tags: c++, templates

What are the advantages (in addition to maintainability) of writing a class template that is meaningful for 2 types only (i.e. `float` and `double`)?

Comment: The same advantage of implementing a template instantiable by N types; Nx less replicate code. In this case N=2. Were you looking for a reason *not* to do it?

Comment: @WhozCraig: we are focusing on numerical algorithms and floats are hardly useful for us. I am looking for a reason to actually use templates even though floats are barely used.

Comment: there is a big difference between "barely used" and "not used". Whether you want to take the load of maintaining two code sets for different types is up to you.

Comment: @WhozCraig: we actually only support double version. So I am looking for "other" advantages to convince people that template versions are worth the time spent.

Comment: If you are only using `double` right now - then it's a case of YAGNII so don't do it. Use templates when they solve a problem. Don't invent reasons to make the code more complex, code is often complex enough without invented reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintainability is the one single advantage, you want to keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) without duplicated code.

I don't see any problems with a template for just two types - `float` and `double` are similiar, but there are no other types that behave in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Because it may be applicable to use `std::complex<float>` as a type? It the template is really generic to a floating point (or integer) type, who said that there may not come additional larger types along the road?